# Is there any way to package all python dependency into single executable

Tags: python

We are shipping our product to customers location who may or may not have python and other libraries installed, so can we reduce our python script into an independent executable with python and other required libraries included , so are there other ideas ?

Comment: `pyinstaller` is what your looking for...

Comment: Depends on the operating system. Windows has py2exe, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use py2exe it does exactly what you need, and its very easy to use. I have used it on one of my projects which are online and used daily.

http://www.py2exe.org/

and here is their tutorial:

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

Comment: i see no mention of linux :(

Answer (score -1):

You can deliver a package with Python and then apply one of these two methods:

#### Package With python + virtualenv

There's many solutions for that. One I like is `virtualenv`, which can allow you to deploy a specific configuration of a Python project (with dependencies) on another machines.

#### Package With python + pip

Another way is to use `pip` and write a `requirements.txt` file at the root of your project, which contains every dependency (1 per line), for example:

```
django>=1.5.4
pillow
markdown
django-compressor
```

By doing `pip -r requirements.txt` in the root dir, the program will install packages needed.

---

See also:

- [How do you use pip, virtualenv and Fabric to handle deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441704/how-do-you-use-pip-virtualenv-and-fabric-to-handle-deployment)
- [Pip installer documentation](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/)
- [Virtualenv documentation](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/)

Comment: I meant I do not need to install everything at customer site. Virtual env needs python installation so it wont work