# Ship Python script in a self-contained package? (Linux, Mac, Windows)

Tags: python, linux, windows, macos, executable

I wrote a script which I wish to deploy on Mac OS, Windows and Linux clients. While most Mac and Linux machines have some version of Python, Windows does not. Adding to this there's a module partly written in C that I wish to include.

Currently I'm looking into [freezing](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/freezing/) the code (e.g. py2exe or PyInstaller), but this will get tedious on changes.

Is there a good alternative to ship the script in one self-contained package?

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20358410/1864036) from another thread help?